# Why is my combination/permutation intuition failing so badly?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, intuition

*(My question is at the very bottom.)*

Here's how to calculate the number of possible **permutations when repetition isn't allowed** (i.e. when a sample can't contain the same item multiple times):

$$
\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}
$$

---

Quick reminder:

$n$: the total number of items to choose from (i.e. population size)

$r$: the number of selections you'll make (i.e. sample size)

*Permutation*: A specific selection of items in a specific order

*Combination*: A specific selection of items where the order doesn't matter

---

For **combinations when repetition isn't allowed**, you take the permutation formula and just divide it by $r!$:

$$
\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}\right)}{r!}
$$

Or simplified:

$$
\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}
$$

This makes good intuitive sense:

- With permutations, it matters how your items are ordered; with combinations, the order doesn't matter
- For a given sample of $r$ items, there are $r!$ unique ways to order those items
- Thus, given the number of permutations for a sample of $r$ items, we eliminate all unique orderings by dividing by $r!$, clearly leaving us with the number of combinations.

Moving along, here's the simple formula for **permutations when repetition is allowed**:

$$
n^r
$$

And to calculate the number of **combinations when repetition is allowed**, we repeat the above process—we divide the whole formula by $r!$:

$$
\dfrac{n^r}{r!}
$$

**NO. That's wrong!** The actual formula is:

$$
\dfrac{(n + r - 1)!}{(n - 1)!r!}
$$

**Question:**

When repetition isn't allowed, it makes sense why we divide the permutation formula by $r!$. Why doesn't this same trick work when repetition is allowed?

*(You don't need to spend any time explaining why the correct formula is indeed correct. I just want to understand why we divide by $r!$ in one case but not the other.)*

Comment: You divide by $r!$ in the first case because without repetition every combination comes in exactly $r!$ possible orders. With repetition, the number of orders depends on how many repetitions there are. For example $1234$ can still be permuted into $4!$ different orders but $1111$ can only be permuted into $1$ possible order and $1122$ can be permuted into $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ possible orders, and so forth.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thank you. I've corrected it.

Comment: $n^r/r!$ may not even be an integer.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a group action?

Comment: @DavidK, yes it does. Thank you very much.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, could you please write your comment as a question so that I can give you credit? I am not able to give a `+1` to comments.